# Passing data between android and server using JSON parsing

Tags: java, android, json, servlets, httpconnection

I'm trying to send and receive data between **android** app and **server** using **JSON** but unfortunately i am unable to do it i searched a lot but it didn't help. My code is as follows:

In android

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("fromDate", from);
        jsonObject.put("toDate", to);
        jsonObject.put("reason", reas);
        new SendData().execute(jsonObject);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and then my **asynctask**'s doInBackground method

```
try {
                HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,
                        CmsInter.TIMEOUT);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, CmsInter.TIMEOUT);
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(getResources().getString(
                        R.string.URL));
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(object.toString());
                se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                        "application/json"));
                httpPost.setEntity(se);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
                message = Sync.convertResponseToString(response);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                message = e.toString();
            }
```

and then on server side within the `doPost()` method of servlet code is as follows :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String line = null;
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    sb.append(line);
            } catch (Exception e) { /* report an error */
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String str = sb.toString();
            try {
                org.json.JSONObject json = new org.json.JSONObject(str);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

and I think this is not the right way to read `JSONObject` on the server side because when I run this I get `org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1` exception , Can anyone please help me out in this. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: how are u received data in php? post php file.

Comment: no i'm receiving data in servlet only see my doPost method of servlet

Comment: post the json response too

Comment: my reading log cat what it seems like you are converting the data into json object where as it is jsonarray, use JSONArray

Comment: validate ur json with jason parser first

Comment: this is what i get on this line String str = sb.toString(); when i debug str as [Lorg.json.JSONObject;@2e5b7c9

Comment: @N5. how. can you please elaborate

Comment: @SyedRazaMehdi nope it isn't a JSONarray m creating an JSONObject and simply passing three data in it.

Comment: paste ur json here : http://json.parser.online.fr/ and see it is giveing any erros

Comment: it is not a valid json object either, it is just a string so don't use json object just use it with string or either change the response to proper json object

Comment: this would be the proper json object {Lorg.json.JSONObject;@2e5b7c9}

Comment: so can you tell me how do i pass data between client and server using JSON

Comment: `object.toString()` is what you send. Log it to see what it is. By the way: you did not show what `object` is. So how should we know?

Comment: @greenapps so can you tell me how do i set jsonnobject as entity to Httppost

Comment: Well i asked you to log something and you did not tell the result.

Comment: when i debug i get the object as [{"fromDate":"03\/06\/2015","toDate":"04\/06\/2015","reason":"ghfhfd"}]  and object.toString() as  [Lorg.json.JSONObject;@1d899b4c this.

Comment: You can see that you should not send object.toString() isn't it? And you still did not tell what object is. And `i get the object` ??? How? What are you doing exactly there?

Comment: @greenapps sorry about that silly mistake but i really dont know how to send JSON object in HTTPPOst.setEntity

Comment: You are already sending text with setaentity. So you already know how to send text. You only do not know how to get the right text from youf object.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it this line was wrong `object.toString()` while sending it should have been `object[0].toString()` because asynctask's doInBackground methods parameter is an array i.e. `protected String doInBackground(JSONObject... object)`.